# Neotree window permanently resizes other windows

Tags: window, window-splitting

I usually have my emacs frame something like this:

```
|             |             |
| <window 1>  | <window 2>  |
|             |             |
```

When I open `neotree`, it then looks like this (`N` representing the `neotree` window):

```
|   |             |         |
| N |     W1      |   W2    |
|   |             |         |
```

Then, when I close `neotree`, the windows look like this:

```
|                 |         |
|         W1      |   W2    |
|                 |         |
```

This is aesthetically displeasing and brings window 2's width below 80 characters, so code lines wrap.

Is there a way I can make `neotree-toggle` reset the window sizes to their values in the first diagram?

Comment: Does this happen with `-Q` and only neotree loaded? I am not able to reproduce this.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange. I don't have this problem.
Here my conf:

```
(autoload 'neotree "neotree" "" t) 
(setq neo-window-width 50) 
(setq neo-persist-show nil)
```

I use emacs 25 with the latest neotree.el

Answer (score 0):

Here's the workaround that I use:

- set a hotkey for `neotree-toggle`: `(global-set-key (kbd "M-n") 'neotree-toggle)`
- open 2 or 3 windows side by side: `C-x 3`
- make them the same size: `C-x +`
- open neotree: `M-n`

Additionally, I started using [`winner-mode`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WinnerMode), mainly for maximizing windows: `C-x 1`, then revert to previous window configuration `C-c <left>`.

*Emacs version: `GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0) of 2015-09-13 on elcapitanvm.local`, config file: [emacs.el](https://github.com/andreis/cfg/blob/master/emacs.el)*